# Deploy EAR with Websphere Application Server wsadmin.bat without losing security role-mapping?

Tags: websphere, application

We're running CI towards our WAS with wsadmin.bat

The applications are updated with this command

```
$AdminApp update ${projectName}EAR app {-operation update -update.ignore.new -contents {${artifactsDir}/${projectName}-${buildVersion}.ear}}
```

This causes all the "Security role to user/group mapping"-settings to reset, even though all the other settings are preserved with the **-update.ignore.new**

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

you may want to try:

$AdminApp install instead as the parameter -update -update.ignore.new applies only if you specify install command and there are existing binding and if the existing bindings are older than bindings in the new ear.